# How can I fix Image Exception error when uploading image via front-end form while Preparse plugin enabled?

Tags: assets, craft3, image, frontend-form

I'm not sure if the issue is with Craft 3, the Preparse plugin, or me, so I'm posting here first.

I have a front-end form that includes an Assets field used to upload images. The entry type contains Preparse fields.

When the Preparse plugin is enabled and I submit the front-end form with an image, I get this error:

```
Image Exception – craft\errors\ImageException
The file "assets5bcf19ef8f6bc6.04658934.jpg" does not appear to be an image.
```

Screenshot with more details: https://cl.ly/edfbc0c07bde

The entry still gets created and the .jpg file is uploaded as expected.

I don't have any issues when creating entries via the CP.

If I disable the Preparse plugin and submit the front-end form, the error does not appear.

If I upload a .pdf file instead of a .jpg while the Preparse plugin is enabled, I don't get an error.

Therefore, it appears to be an issue with the Preparse plugin and image files in Craft 3 front-end forms (tested both .jpg & .png).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in Preparse Plugin v 1.0.3.

View changelog at: https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft/blob/craft3/CHANGELOG.md#103---2018-10-24